# Separating __call__ into __new__ and __init__

Tags: python, metaclass

I am trying to write some metaclass for a special case of a `SingletonMeta`.

**This is not a question about Singletons. It is about using metaclasses in Python.**

I need to control `__new__` and `__init__` of the Singleton classes (the instances of `SingletonMeta`) separately, but I was not able to do so. All I managed to do was call them both *together*.

A dumbed down version of my code is currently only using `cls.__call__`, which I want to separate into `__new__` and `__init__`.

Problem is I don't know how parameters are passed within the default `__call__` into `__new__`, and possibly other knowledge gaps.

---

My code, declaring a `SingletonMeta` metaclass, and a `Singleton` concrete class which is its instance.

```
class SingletonMetaMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs):  # args passed on import time with class Singleton(metaclass=NonInheritableSingletonMetaMeta)
        print(f"SingletonMeta __new__, args:{args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls

    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"SingletonMetaMeta __init__, args:{args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")
        super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.__instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"SingletonMeta __call__, args:{args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.__instance


class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMetaMeta):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Singleton __new__, args:{args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        return self

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Singleton __init__, args:{args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Singleton __call__, args:{args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")


print("class created")

instance = Singleton(1)

print("instance created")
```

outputs

```
SingletonMeta __new__, args:('Singleton', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Singleton', '__new__': <function Singleton.__new__ at 0x7f790a09d5e0>, '__init__': <function Singleton.__init__ at 0x7f790a09d670>, '__call__': <function Singleton.__call__ at 0x7f790a09d700>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f79238e61c0: empty>}), kwargs: {}
SingletonMetaMeta __init__, args:('Singleton', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Singleton', '__new__': <function Singleton.__new__ at 0x7f790a09d5e0>, '__init__': <function Singleton.__init__ at 0x7f790a09d670>, '__call__': <function Singleton.__call__ at 0x7f790a09d700>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f79238e61c0: SingletonMetaMeta object at 0x5631858c8fb0>}), kwargs: {}
class created
SingletonMeta __call__, args:(1,), kwargs: {}
Singleton __new__, args:(1,), kwargs: {}
Singleton __init__, args:(1,), kwargs: {}
instance created
```

showing `super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)` in `SingletonMetaMeta`'s `__call__` indeed calls the classes' `__new__` then `__init__`.

How can I interfere with that process? I want to manually call them myself.

---

### My attempt

Trying to replace `cls.__instance = super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)`

with

```
            instance = cls.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
            instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

gives

```
SingletonMeta __new__, args:('Singleton', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Singleton', '__new__': <function Singleton.__new__ at 0x7f5c0c9d35e0>, '__init__': <function Singleton.__init__ at 0x7f5c0c9d3670>, '__call__': <function Singleton.__call__ at 0x7f5c0c9d3700>, 'foo': <function Singleton.foo at 0x7f5c0c9d3790>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f5c2621d1c0: empty>}), kwargs: {}
SingletonMetaMeta __init__, args:('Singleton', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Singleton', '__new__': <function Singleton.__new__ at 0x7f5c0c9d35e0>, '__init__': <function Singleton.__init__ at 0x7f5c0c9d3670>, '__call__': <function Singleton.__call__ at 0x7f5c0c9d3700>, 'foo': <function Singleton.foo at 0x7f5c0c9d3790>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f5c2621d1c0: SingletonMetaMeta object at 0x55ecc6137fb0>}), kwargs: {}
class created
SingletonMeta __call__, args:(1,), kwargs: {}
Singleton __new__, args:(), kwargs: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_metadata/utils/asd.py", line 41, in <module>
    instance = Singleton(1)
  File "/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_metadata/utils/asd.py", line 16, in __call__
    instance = cls.__new__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_metadata/utils/asd.py", line 24, in __new__
    self = super().__new__(cls)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Trying to replace `cls.__instance = super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)`

with

```
            instance = super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__new__(*args, **kwargs)
            instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

gives

```
SingletonMeta __new__, args:('Singleton', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Singleton', '__new__': <function Singleton.__new__ at 0x7f7aefc875e0>, '__init__': <function Singleton.__init__ at 0x7f7aefc87670>, '__call__': <function Singleton.__call__ at 0x7f7aefc87700>, 'foo': <function Singleton.foo at 0x7f7aefc87790>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f7b094d01c0: empty>}), kwargs: {}
SingletonMetaMeta __init__, args:('Singleton', (), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'Singleton', '__new__': <function Singleton.__new__ at 0x7f7aefc875e0>, '__init__': <function Singleton.__init__ at 0x7f7aefc87670>, '__call__': <function Singleton.__call__ at 0x7f7aefc87700>, 'foo': <function Singleton.foo at 0x7f7aefc87790>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f7b094d01c0: SingletonMetaMeta object at 0x55b942d98fb0>}), kwargs: {}
class created
SingletonMeta __call__, args:(1,), kwargs: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_metadata/utils/asd.py", line 41, in <module>
    instance = Singleton(1)
  File "/home/noam.s/src/uv_metadata/uv_metadata/utils/asd.py", line 16, in __call__
    instance = super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__new__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: type.__new__(X): X is not a type object (int)
```

---

What's the correct way to separate `__call__` in this case?

Bonus: Can the same be done for the call of `type`, thus changing what happens on the line `class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMetaMeta):`?

Comment: @chepner This is not an XY problem because 1. It is an attempt to understand metaclasses via Singletons 2. There are many cases where Singletons ARE correct.

Comment: @chepner I will still refer to the link, even though it is unrelated. Though that article has a good point (separation of what the class does from how many instances of it exists) it doesn't offer an alternative. Furthermore, it lazily claims "You can’t defend against every bug, and it’s their program anyway.". This is simply bad practice. If library code can defend its users, it should. I would only accept articles like this if another neat way of doing the same is proposed instead.

Comment: Why do you need to *defend* against multiple instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to replace

```
cls.__instance = super(SingletonMetaMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

with

```
instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `__new__`  method of a class is special in that it is an static method, and its first argument, the class which it belongs to, always have to be passed explicitly. `__init__` on the other hand is an ordinary method for this purpose, and Python will insert the `self` argument as usual in the call.

Still: using metaclasses for singletons in Python is way overkill, and an antipattern. Just create a module level instance of a class, and, if needed, delete the class from the namespace will work in most cases.

```
class Singleton:
    ...

singleton = Singleton
del Singleton
```

If users of your singleton should try to create a new instance, and just get the same, instead of having a created object like "None", "True", you can write a `__call__` method which returns `self` and name the instance the same as the class instead:

```
class Singleton:
    ...
    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
         return self

Singleton = Singleton()

# no need for `del` here: the class declaration have been 
# superseded by the instance.
```

Comment: Well, looks like it works, thanks! However: 1. Pycharm doesn't like that I pass `cls` into `cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` with `Expected type 'Type[SingletonMetaMeta]', got 'SingletonMetaMeta' instead`. What's going on there? 2. What is the meaning of the error I got when trying `instance = cls.__new__(*args, **kwargs)`? The error has nothing to say about a missing `cls` argument.

Comment: As for the specific Singleton technique, thanks, I learned something. Still, the addition of `__call__`, and `Singleton = Singleton()` on each and every Singleton is something I am looking to avoid. I also have more requirements I want Singletons to hold, which are not stated here.

Comment: let pycharm complain. This is the kind of things that static type checking and annotations make much harder - and you probably could just skip annotations in this part.  When dealing with metaclasses correct type annotations many times is not even possible, because the class creation mechanism is not followed by the static tooling.